# Is it Possible To Change Material with Duplicate Geo Nodes referencing itself?

Tags: geometry-nodes

So I wanted to Create a Geo Node Setup That Can Dynamically Change Material based on Neighboring Duplicated objects.

[image]

This is Possible when Instancing Collection Data and Plugging it into a Geometry Proximity node.
If the Instance is in Contact with the Original Object, the material will then select the faces in contact with the instanced objects, and then assign a given material.

[image]

However, when I try Referencing itself, Geometry cant be retrieved from the Object info; forcing the Material to apply on all faces and it's duplicates. I suspect Object info has nothing to track the position of each Duplicate. Unfortunately, my brain is too smooth to come up with something like that.

[image]

Am I SOL, or is there something that could resolve this?

Comment: Not really sure what you're exactly trying to do. Why not choose Cube.003 from the Object Info dropdown? By "duplicate" do you mean linked duplicate (Alt+D)? Even if they're linked duplicates, they would still be different objects, so Self Object wouldn't enter into the discussion (your distance to yourself will always be zero anyways)? In short, why are you trying NOT to use the Collection Info method when it is already working?

Comment: I'm attempting to Create a residential Home with Geometry nodes. by Treating Each object as an individual "room". each room has 2 kinds of walls, an Interior Wall and an exterior wall. Prox Geo could in theory discern between the two

Comment: but to repeat the same effect on other objects it does not produce the desired result with this current setup.

Comment: Oh, by "duplicate" you mean other objects with the same geometry nodes, not that objects are necessarily the same. So you want all objects with this GN modifier to "see" each other?

Comment: you are correct :)